# Accumulation of zeros for a $C^3$ function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Is there a $C^3$ function $v(x,y)$ such that :

- $v\left(\frac{1}{n},0\right)=0$  for all  $n\in\{1,2,\ldots\}$
- $v\left(\frac{1}{n+\frac{1}{2}},0\right)\neq0$ for all  $n\in\{1,2,\ldots\}$
- $Dv(0,0)=(0,1)$
- $D^2v(0,0)\neq \left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\right)$ ?

This is a simplified version of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737153/level-sets-and-derivative).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to define $x\mapsto v(x,0)$, you can use

Let $f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}e^{-\cfrac{1}{x^2}}\text{ if }x > 0\\0\text{ otherwise}\end{array}\right.$

Now take $g(x) = f(x)f(1-x)$. $g(x)=0\iff x>0\land 1-x > 0\iff x > 0\land 1 > x\iff x \in (0,1)$.

$g$ is $C^\infty$ has all its derivatives at $0$ and $1$ equal to $0$.

The fact that the derivatives are equal to $0$ on the borders mean you can put several functions like that one next to the other and still have a $C^\infty$ function. Also, since it is equal to $0$ on the borders and not equal to $0$ elsewhere, it's easy to build a function that satisfies your first two conditions.

To have your third condition verified, you would have to be a bit more careful. Since you reduce the width of the $g$-like functions would will use as you get closer to $0$, you will also have to scale them down to make sure their derivatives aren't getting too big. Since it's $C^\infty$ on a segment, the derivative is bounded so you can do that. That gives you the $0$ of $(0,1)$.

And for the remaining conditions, just defining $v(0,y)$ properly and letting $v(x,y)=v(x,0)+v(0,y)$ should do the trick.

Comment: Do you think it is also possible to find a counter-example where the non zero component is the off diagonal entry ?

Comment: Many thanks! An example amongst the ones you suggested is 
$$
v(x,y):=y-y^2 +\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^8}g\left(n\left((n+1)x-1\right)\right).
$$
Very nice.

Comment: @walt: It's probably possible by replacing $v(0,y)$ by $w(x,y)$ in the equality. But I can't see any obvious example.

Comment: You are right. $y+xy$ works. Adieu veaux, vaches, cochons..

Comment: If you have an idea of what the equivalent of $\det(Du,Dv)\neq0$ is for $n=2$, in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737153/level-sets-and-derivative).. The correct version of the question is. Assuming $\det(Du,Dv)=0$ ($Du\neq0$, $Dv\neq0$) whare are sufficient conditions on  $D^2u$ and $D^2v$ so that the intersection is the origin. An easy one is $\det(D^2(u-v))>0$  but are there others?